# Retrieve Selected Text from a Web Browser Control in a

Tags: c#, wpf, text, webbrowser-control, selected

Here's what I am trying to do:

Select text from a webpage I pulled up using my web browser control.After clicking a button while this text is still selected I would like a message box to pop-up displaying the text that was highlighted by the user. How do I get this functionality to work in my wpf application?

I think I'm on the right track using mshtml but I get an error that says:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

This error will happen even when I try something small on the document like changing the title.

The code is below:

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)this.webBookText.Document;
doc.title = "l";
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters it would be a lot simpler to use [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) than mshtml (note that you can still host `WebBrowser` in WPF) - this will certainly let you do simple things a lot easier:

```
webBook.Document.Title = "foo";
```

However, I can't see anything there that would let you work with selections very easily...

You can get the selected *element* with `.Document.ActiveElement`, but this is the entire element - not the selected portion.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out that error was because this wasn't in my form class